# How does the matcher traverse the string while looking for matching characters?

Tags: java, regex, string, quantifiers

The quantifier `a?` is supposed to match `a single or no occurrence of a`. The given program uses `java.util.regex` package to match a regex with a string.

My question is about the output of the program/result of the pattern matching:

**Output of the program:-**

`Enter your regex: a?
Enter input string to search: a
I found the text "a" starting at index 0 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1.`

**Question:-**

It is supposed to match one or zero occurrence of a. **So shouldn't it match a `zero-length ""` (that is absence/zero times occurrence of `a`) `starting and ending at index 0`, then match `a` `starting at index 0` and `ending at index 0`, and then a `""` `starting and ending at index 1`?** I think it should.

This way it seems like the `matcher` keeps looking for `a`'s though-out the string, and then when it is sure that there are no more `a`'s (that is the `end` of the string? ) then it looks for the `zero occurrence`/ absence of `a`? I think that would be tedious and that would not be the case. But then it should find a "" `starting and ending at 0` before it matches a starting at `index 0` and ending at `index 1`?

**Program:-**

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/*
 *  Enter your regex: foo
 *  Enter input string to search: foo
 *  I found the text foo starting at index 0 and ending at index 3.
 * */

public class RegexTestHarness {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        /*Console console = System.console();
        if (console == null) {
            System.err.println("No console.");
            System.exit(1);
        }*/

        while (true) {

            /*Pattern pattern = 
            Pattern.compile(console.readLine("%nEnter your regex: ", null));*/

            System.out.print("\nEnter your regex: ");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(scanner.next());

            System.out.print("\nEnter your input string to seacrh: ");

            Matcher matcher = 
            pattern.matcher(scanner.next());

            System.out.println();

            boolean found = false;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                /*console.format("I found the text" +
                    " \"%s\" starting at " +
                    "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                    matcher.group(),
                    matcher.start(),
                    matcher.end());*/

                System.out.println("I found the text \"" + matcher.group() + "\" starting at index " + matcher.start() + " and ending at index " + matcher.end() + "."); 

                found = true;
            }
            if(!found){
                //console.format("No match found.%n", null);
                System.out.println("No match found."); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` quantifier is **greedy** which means it will try to find maximal possible match. Since matched part can't be reused you are not able to match empty string `""` before `a` (you can think of it as par of first greedy match) but you are able to match empty string after it.

You can make it **reluctant** by adding `?` after this quantifier which will make it try find minimal possible match. So if you will try to find match of regex `a??` you will see `0` as index of first match (which will be empty string before `a`).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was following [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) tutorial and was in the start, did not know what a greedy quantifier is, but this answer clarified it.

Comment: Hi, I am confused again. You said that the `""` string before `a` was already part of the first greedy match. I think it was not, the first greedy match found `a` only and not the `""` before it. How is `""` before `a` a *part of the first greedy match*?

Comment: @Zarah What I mean't was that since `?` is looking for maximal possible match and since `a` could be used here `""` couldn't be returned. Lets visualize it this way: we have regex `a{1,3}` and string `"aaa"`. Regex engine will find `a` and will accept it in temporary match but will not return it yet (engine doesn't know if this is maximal match) so it test next character. Since it finds another `a` it includes it in current match (so it does something like `"a"+"a"`) so it has now `aa` and again it doesn't return match yet because it wants to test next character. And again it finds `a` so

Comment: @Zarah it adds to current match. Now this is maximal match which could be found so engine returns it ("aaa"). Similar thing happens with `a?` which is `a{0,1}`, at start regex engine finds empty string which matches case `a{0}` but doesn't return it yet because it wants to check if there is possibility for larger match (it is greedy so it wants to find maximal match). Since it finds `a` it adds it to match. In other words it adds this `a` to already matched empty string `""` that is why I said that empty string is part of the match.